# Using and creating a custom 2 way encryption function

Tags: encryption, php, decryption

I am trying to create a 2 way encryption function using PHP.

As yet I do not have a very good system at all, it is severely flawed and highly insecure, it is using a substitute cipher running from the periodic table of elements (this is not what want, but what I am working on making better).

My question is as follows:

*What is the best way to create a symmetric key algorithm that both creates a salt for a string to be encrypted with and a decrypt function using the same salt and algorithm that is safe, secure and maintainable? What do I have to look out for that creates a weakness/vulnerability within the code/crypto function?*

For what I have now, please see [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114881/custom-algorithm-for-hashing-and-un-hashing-password) on codereview.stackexchange.

Notes:

- This is not going to be used as a "rolled out" product, it is purely for training and development purposes
- I understand that this may very well be off topic, if so please say and I'll remove this question

Comment: Just letting you know that StackExchange also has a site dedicated to [crypto.se] which may be a good choice for such training question. However, I fear that stated as it is now ("*What is the best way? What do you I have to look out?*") it may be seen as too broad, better ask on advises on how to solve precise issues you are encountering now, or maybe on list of properties and tests you can use to determine your hash function quality, etc.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf, thank you for that, I will rethink my question and migrate to there, cheers for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not attempt to create your own crypto algorithm for production use. Creating crypto systems is work for highly specialised *teams* of cryptographers, but everybody needs to start somewhere off course. ^_^

Instead, use a well known cryptographic algorithm. If at all possible (and it *is* possible), use a class that encapsulates all the configuration options for you and provides dummy proof methods.

Take a look at:

- [Pixelfck/SymmetricEncryption](https://github.com/Pixelfck/SymmetricEncryption) For an easy 'drop-in' solution (their words, not mine).
- [Libsodium](https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium) For a more elaborate (hence a bit complex) library.

Normally, I would say: whatever you do, don't go editing the source code provided: a tiny seemingly insignificant edit can jeopardize the whole library, and you won't even know it.

BUT: since you indicate that you want to learn from it, studying and toying around those two solutions may give you a nice start.